# Test suite will not load into VSCode Ruby Test Explorer

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

I am trying to utilize VSCode's Ruby Test Explorer extension but it is failing to load my test suite.

My tests are all in a ./test/ folder in my root directory. This is my Test Explorer setup:

```
    "rubyTestExplorer.testFramework": "rspec", 
    "rubyTestExplorer.rspecCommand": "rspec",
    "rubyTestExplorer.rspecDirectory": "./test/", 
    "rubyTestExplorer.logpanel": true
```

The logger output is displaying the following:

> [2020-05-22 17:10:53.877] [INFO] Running Ruby tests ["root"]
>   [2020-05-22 17:10:53.878] [INFO] Running full test suite.
>   [2020-05-22 17:10:53.878] [INFO] Running command: rspec --require /Users/Home/.vscode/extensions/connorshea.vscode-ruby-test-adapter-0.7.1/custom_formatter.rb --format CustomFormatter
>   [2020-05-22 17:10:54.095] [DEBUG] [CHILD PROCESS OUTPUT] START_OF_TEST_JSON{"version":"3.9.2","messages":["No examples found."],"examples":[],"summary":{"duration":0.000242,"example_count":0,"failure_count":0,"pending_count":0,"errors_outside_of_examples_count":0},"summary_line":"0 examples, 0 failures"}END_OF_TEST_JSON
>   [2020-05-22 17:10:54.096] [DEBUG] Parsing the below JSON:
>   [2020-05-22 17:10:54.096] [DEBUG] {"version":"3.9.2","messages":["No examples found."],"examples":[],"summary":{"duration":0.000242,"example_count":0,"failure_count":0,"pending_count":0,"errors_outside_of_examples_count":0},"summary_line":"0 examples, 0 failures"}
>   [2020-05-22 17:10:54.102] [INFO] Child process has exited. Sending test run finish event.

The Test Explorer panel remains blank.